# Match string between multiple brackets

Tags: java, regex, json

I have this very long JSON string. I would like to filtrate it and only get the data between the first bracket. The problem is, I have many other brackets therefore my regex pattern is not working properly.

Here is the JSON string:

```
    String jsondata = "["
    +"{"
      +  "test: 63453645"
        +"date: 2016-07-17"
       "{"
        + "id:534534"
        +"}"
      + "blank : null"
      + "flags : null"
     + "}"
    +"{"
      +  "test: 543564236"
        +"date: 2014-07-17"
        +"{"
        + "id:6532465"
        +"}"
      + "blank : null"
      + "flags : null"
    + "}"
    +"]";

    pattern = "\\{[^{}]*\\}";
    pr = Pattern.compile(pattern);  
    math = pr.matcher(jsondata);
    if (math.find()) {
        System.out.println(math.group());
    }
    else
        System.out.println("nomatch");
```

The problem with the pattern that I have is that it only prints out to the first `}` after the `id:`, but I want it to end at the last `}` which is after flags: null.

And I only want to print the first match, i.e not the string after because the also start and end with the same character, and that is why I have an if statement instead of a while loop.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Regex with multiple brackets seems like a very difficult task. Can I match the last string instead? Starting from `{` to `flags : null`?

Comment: unfortunately you can't deal with nested brackets in java with regex. use a json parser.

Comment: I usually make use of [JSON-Simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).
A great tutorial, [decoding](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples).

Comment: Also, that is not valid Java code, and if it was, jsondata would be invalid JSON.

Comment: json is not regex parseable, you need a stateful parser for that.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in comment,
I usually make use of [JSON-Simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).
A great tutorial, [decoding](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples).

would look somewhat like:

```
JSONObject obj = JSONValue.parse(jsondata);
obj.get("test");
```

PS.
I do see some errors in your json data, make use of [jsonlint](http://pro.jsonlint.com/) to verify if your json is formatted correctly...

Comment: In your code i don't see you use the `jsondata` object ? should `responseData`be replaced with `jsondata`? Is it a temp var?

Comment: It was a typo. Sorry.

Comment: Can i ask you why you use json if you are just going to use regex afterwards ? Json decoding can be soo easy, but you must create your json correctly....

Answer (score 0):

This will grab everything between the first `{` and last `}`:

```
String guts = jsondata.replaceAll("(?s)^.*?\\{(.*?flags : null[^}]*).*$", "$1");
```

The regex captures everything after the first `{` up to your semaphore text and all non-`}` chars following.

Comment: Thank you, but I dont want the last }. I want the } after the first "flags:null".